# Understanding Java's GC logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, logging

I turned on verbose GC options on my JDK, and now I'm seeing lines such as

```
25.598: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
25.622: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.023/0.024 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
25.623: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
25.629: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.007/0.007 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Anyone care to tell me exactly what all the parameters there mean?

1. What's the difference between sys+user and real times?
2. What does "0.023/0.024 secs" mean?

Comment: Which jdk version? I found this article for JDK5, but the output looks different (and they mention, output varies with JDK version) http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/submitted/cms_gc_logs.html , the two numbers `0.023/0.024` are CPU/wall times.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's just related to CPU usage..

1. *real* is the absolute difference of time between end and start (not excluding context switches)
2. *user* is how much time is spent while executing code in user space
3. *sys* is how much time is spent while execting system code (eg. system calls or everything else that moves control from user code to kernel code)

A note: while *real* doesn't represent effective time (because of including also time in which GC goes away from CPU to let it to something else) *sys+user* does.

**EDIT**

`CMS-concurrent-sweep` is the phase in which GC actually cleans useless objects (it's done after the marking phase). In this case it's concurrent because GC works together with application without pausing it and time should be time used (maybe `time-start / time-end`, not sure about that)

Comment: Do you know what the two numbers next to the GC's name represent?

Comment: where are you talking about exactly? Which numbers?